# Python 3 add the total of numbers in a string which also contains letters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string like:

```
foundstring = 'a1b2c3d4'
```

And want to add each number for a total like:

```
1+2+3+4
```

So I thought I could use something like making the string to a list and a function using isdigit() to add a running total of the digits in the list like this

```
 listset = list(foundstring)
def get_digits_total(list1):
total = 0
for I in list1:
    if I.isdigit():
         total += I

        return total
```

Which gives you a list like `['a', '1', 'b', '2', 'c', '3', 'd', '4']` 
But that throws an error

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'
```

I know there is a very easy way to do this and Im probably making it too complicated. Im trying out some stuff with list comprehension but haven't been able to get `isinstance()` to do what I want so far

Comment: Would you want `a1b23` to give `1+2+3==6` or `1+23==24`?

Comment: So where exactly is `return total` indented to? Can you fix the indentation please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
total += i
```

with

```
total += int(i)
```

`total` is an integer. `i` is a string (always a single character from `foundstring`), although one of `0123456789`. In order to "add" it to `total`, you have to convert it to an integer.

```
'1' + '2' = '12'  # strings
1 + 2 = 3         # integers
```

As a further inspiration, you can write your `get_digits_total` as:

```
total = sum(int(i) for i in foundstring if i.isdigit())
```

even without converting `foundstring` to a list, because iterating over a string returns individual characters.

Comment: Nice thanks! Always good to learn new ways to reduce the number of lines of code!